# Difference between modelAttribute and commandName

Tags: forms, spring, spring-mvc, jstl

What is the difference between using commandName and modelAttribute when sending form data?

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="csvFileUploadVO">
```

and

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="csvFileUploadVO">
```

At which point of time should I use either of them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495616/difference-between-modelattribute-and-commandname-atributes-in-form-tag-in-sprin

refer this link it will give you detailed information

Answer (score 27):

There is no difference, two different attributes exist for historical reasons.

Comment: True, in code, inside `FormTag` there is `public void setCommandName(String commandName) { this.modelAttribute = commandName; }`