# Difference between modelAttribute and commandName attributes in form tag in spring?

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, modelattribute

In Spring 3, I have seen two different attribute in form tag in jsp

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="login">
```

in this the attribute modelAttribute  is the name of the form object whose properties are used to populate the form. And I used it in posting a form and in controller I have used `@ModelAttribute` to capture value, calling validator, applying business logic. Everything is fine here. Now

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="login">
```

What is expected by this attribute, is it also a form object whose properties we are going to populate?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

If you look at the [source code of `FormTag` (4.3.x)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.3.x/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/FormTag.java#L53) which backs your `<form>` element, you'll notice this

```
/**
 * Set the name of the form attribute in the model.
 * <p>May be a runtime expression.
 */
public void setModelAttribute(String modelAttribute) {
    this.modelAttribute = modelAttribute;
}

/**
 * Get the name of the form attribute in the model.
 */
protected String getModelAttribute() {
    return this.modelAttribute;
}

/**
 * Set the name of the form attribute in the model.
 * <p>May be a runtime expression.
 * @see #setModelAttribute
 */
public void setCommandName(String commandName) {
    this.modelAttribute = commandName;
}

/**
 * Get the name of the form attribute in the model.
 * @see #getModelAttribute
 */
protected String getCommandName() {
    return this.modelAttribute;
}
```

They are both referring to the same field, thus having same effect.

But, as the field name indicates, `modelAttribute` should be preferred, as others have also pointed out.

Comment: Good! How did you find out the name the class related to the from tag?

Comment: @Sangdol Conventionally, the class is just called `<tag-name>Tag`. For the fully qualified class name, open the library (`.jar`) containing the tag, `spring-web` in this case. Under `META-INF`, you'll find `spring-form.tld`. It'll have a `<tag>` entry for `form` with a `<tag-class>` of `org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag`.

Answer (score 25):

OLD WAY = commandName

```
...
<spring:url value="/manage/add.do" var="action" />
    <form:form action="${action}" commandName="employee">
        <div>
            <table>
....
```

NEW WAY = modelAttribute

```
..
<spring:url value="/manage/add.do" var="action" />
    <form:form action="${action}" modelAttribute="employee">
        <div>
            <table>
..
```

Answer (score 14):

I had the same question a while ago, I can't remember the exact differences but from research I ascertained that `commandName` was the old way of doing it and in new applications you should be using `modelAttribute`

Answer (score 1):

commandName = name of a variable in the request scope or session scope that contains the information about this form,or this is model for this view. Tt should be a been.

Answer (score -3):

In xml based config, we will use command class to pass an object between controller and views. Now in annotation we are using `modelattribute`.