# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute HTTP Status 500

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am building an application using spring and hibernate.

I think have a problem with `modelAttribute`, but I don't know what is wrong.

This is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2">
        <title>Dziennik pracy</title>
    </head>
        <body>
             <form:form id="loginForm" modelAttribute="user" action="loginUser" method="post">

                       <form:input path="userName"/>
                       <form:input path="password"/>

            </form:form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**My controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {


    @RequestMapping("/showLogin")
    public String showLoginPanel() {
        return "login-user";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/loginUser" )
    public String loginUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model theModel) {
            theModel.addAttribute("user", new User());
            return "user-panel";
    }
}
```

**My entity**

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    int id;

    @Column(name="user_name")
    String userName;

    @Column(name="password")
    String password;
```

**and this is error:**

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add BindingResult object in method signature.

```
public String loginUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,BindingResult result, Model theModel) {
            theModel.addAttribute("user", new User());
            return "user-panel";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your jsp file you have use spring form tag like,

```
 <form:form id="loginForm" modelAttribute="user" action="loginUser" method="post">
```

Here to map spring form with user model entity, you need to use attribute commandName="user" in form tag so tag will be,

```
<form:form id="loginForm" commandName="user" action="loginUser" method="post">
```

Try above solution.

Comment: technically there is no difference between both ...see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495616/difference-between-modelattribute-and-commandname-attributes-in-form-tag-in-spri

Comment: I try it but now i have this : 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/view/login-user.jsp (line: [12], column: [5]) Unable to find setter method for attribute: [commandName]
I check all and I have all field in the jsp and entity class correct to convention setters spring. I want solve this not run away it.